# Ĉu titoloj estu en la akuzativo?

Tags: accusative

Jen kelkaj ekzemploj:

> Li renkontos profesoro Wáng en Berlino.
>
> Mi ne vidis doktoro Müller hodiaŭ.
>
> Tio ne interesus sinjorino Fischer.

Ĉu oni metu la akuzativan n-finaĵon je la titolo, aŭ ĉu oni traktu ĝin kiel parto de la nomo kaj lasu ĝin sen -n?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi dirus ke jes, la titolo bezonas la akuzativon. Se oni serĉas la jenan ĉenon en [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/) aperas 62 ekzemploj.

```
(profesor|doktor|sinjor)(in)?on [A-ZĤŜĜĈĴŬ]
```

Jen kelkaj el ili:

De *Fundamenta Krestomatio de la Lingvo Esperanto*:

> Li petegis **sinjorinon Anneton** alveturi al li en B-n

De *Monato*:

> Li tamen ne deziris ĝeni **doktorinon Donova**.

De *La Ondo de Esperanto*:

> La fama foto, afable sendita de CO UEA, prezentas **profesoron Waringhien** kun la manuskripto de PIV antaŭ transdoni ĝin al la eldonejo

PMEG nomas ĉi tiun koncepton «[identiga prisribo](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/identiga.html)». Ĝi ne rekte specifas ĉu oni metu la n-finaĵon ĉe la *titolo* sed ĝi ja enhavas kelkajn ekzemplojn kie tio okazas. Interese estas ke ĝi [diras ke estis ŝanĝo](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/identiga.html#i-vls) de la reguloj pri la meto de la n-finaĵo ĉe la *nomo*. Ŝajne originale Zamenhof ja farus tion, sed nuntempe oni ne plu faras. La unua ekzemplo montras tiun diferencon. Nuntempe tio estus:

> Li petegis sinjorinon Anneto alveturi al li en B-n

T.e. sen la n-finaĵo ĉe «Anneto».

Comment: Kion vi celas per la suba parto? Kion oni ne plu faras?

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro mi ĵus redaktis la respondon kun ekzemplo de la ŝanĝo kaj ligilo al la priskribo de la diferenco. Espereble tio nun estas pli klara.

Comment: Ah, nun mi komprenas, dankon.